# New Android Gradle Build System build configs package name conflicts with Provider Authority

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I've updated my project to use the new Gradle based build system, largely because I've been kind of annoyed that I can't have my app installed on my device to use it since I use the device for development.  I saw a lot of promise in the `packageNameSuffix` offering of the new build system.

The problem that I'm running into involves things other than the package name in the manifest.  There are other parts that have to be unique, including permissions (specifically for GCM) and ContentProvider Authorities.  When trying to install with a `.debug` suffix I get errors that the GCM permission for that package hasn't been defined and that I'm trying to install a duplicate provider.

Is there a variable that I can put in my manifest instead of these strings so that the build system will replace those appropriately as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution for GCM problems with packageNameSuffix.

Primary problem is permission names that should have ".debug" suffix. I put that permission to debug and release manifests that are merged to final manifest.

AndroidManfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.experiment.myapplication"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

debug AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.experiment.myapplication">


    <permission android:name="com.experiment.myapplication.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.experiment.myapplication.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application>
        <receiver
                android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.experiment.myapplication.debug" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest
```

>

release Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.experiment.myapplication" >

    <permission android:name="com.experiment.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.experiment.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application>
        <receiver
                android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.experiment.myapplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When using the new play services instead of the old gcm-client you don't need the package-specific permission.

Comment: I tried to use this solution with Urban Airship and it did not work as expected. I am still getting the merge conflicts on the package names.

Comment: @deekay it is not. :3

Answer (score 6):

This is a current known limitation of changing the package name for a variant. I'm planning on fixing this as soon as possible.

Comment: Is it fixed or not. Could you add link to issue tracker to track this issue?

Comment: we've just started working on a new manifest merger that will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced all my app's package name in AndroidManifest.xml with placeholder ${packageName}, so Manifest Merger does all work

For example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${packageName}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Android will add the current package name automatically, as you started with a `.`.